# How to interrupt user touch programmatically?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a `ViewPager`. If a user swipes right then I want to interrupt the touch, but if the user swipes left, no interruption.

How can I accomplish this, and how can I interrupt user touch in general?

Comment: Do you want to consume the touch event?

Comment: maybe try to override the ontouchListener method ?

Comment: you need to create custom viewpager and  overrde onInterceptTouchEvent()